# File vanished from Visual Studio 2017 Solution Explorer

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, solution-explorer

I was working on a ASP.NET MVC project when, between two debugs, my main controller simply vanished from the project. I didn't delete or remove it, it's not in my trash folder, neither it's visible when "Show all files" is selected. Searched the whole computer and it's nowhere to be found.
Since it's not a very important project, only part of a training, there is no backup.

Is there anything that can be done to restore it? Has this happened to anyone else?

Comment: I have never heard of VS deleting something without it being asked to. If you have been running up the app in debug it may well have left a copy of it (with a different name) in the Temp files area in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files  or in C:\Users\symeonb\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0 somewhere  (paths above dependent on OS and VS version)

Comment: VS usually warns if some file has been deleted from the project, but not for just excluding it from project. If you're ever running the app, a copy will created on `Temporary ASP.NET Files`, or if you can't found it entirely, use last compiled DLL when the controller code still exists and use certain tools like ILSpy to see source code from missing controller.

Comment: Yes, it just happened to me using VS 2017 in an asp.net project. I lost a major user control and two web pages. They just vanished. They are not where they were in the file system, and are not in the recycle bin. I using and coding the user control all day. I have an old version from yesterday, but it is at least a whole day's work gone!
Did you ever find a solution?